# Laravel form validation issues (session size limit?)

Tags: php, laravel, validation, xampp

I have a form with about 30 inputs that should be validated. This is quite fresh Laravel installation and I handle the validation in controller. It's a simple project and everything is basicly from Laravel docs, so there's not much to show you when it comes to the code itself.

The issue has something to do with the amount of failing fields or the amount of rules, but I can't get my head around it.

If I submit the form without filling any of the input fields, validation fails and I get redirected back to the form, BUT without validation errors OR old input data. 
Same thing if I fill one input and then submit, I'm redirected back without errors or old value of the input I filled.

However,

1. If I fill 7 input fields and submit, everything works. After redirection, those 7 fields has old values and the rest has error messages.
2. If I comment out 7 rules from the validation rule array, it obviously works the same way as above.
3. If I use `Validator::make` and manually redirect back and use `->withErrors($validator)`, the errors shows at the form. The same way, if I use `->withInput()` on the redirect, form will have all the old data. However, using both of these together, wont return errors nor old data back to form.

When this issue happens, debug bar shows
`array:2 [ "old" => [] "new" => [] ]` for `_flash` and session doesn't seem to have `errors` or `_old_input` defined at all.

This is 100% consistent, so it's definitely the amount that causes it, no matter which rules or fields I fill or comment out.

It happens indentically with both
`$request->validate($myRules);` and
`$v = Validator::make($request->all(), $myRules);`

I haven't found much from Google regarding this kinda of behaviour. Just in case, I've changed session driver to `file`, but it didn't help.

I'm currently running on XAMP. (`memory_limit=512M`)

**Edit**:

My final validation logic involves some "if-situations", like:

```
$v->sometimes('description', 'required|max:500', function ($input){
    return $input->publish == 1;
});
```

And now when I've utilized these situations, I noticed that they actually decrease the sketchy "limit" of my issue. So by adding this single sometimes-condition and removing the `description` rule from main rule array, I only need to fill 6 fields anymore to make everything work.

In the end the form will surely have required attributes set to the inputs, so this issue wont happen in real-life scenario, yet it still annoys me a lot, as there must be something causing this and later on it might cause something else too.

**Edit2**:

I made a new form, with 22 inputs and named them with logic: f1, f2, f3, and so on, and it works perfectly!

But updated few of them with a bit longer names, like: f1, f2long, f3, f4evenlonger, etc, and suddenly the problem came back. Then I removed few characters again, and found a spot where it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

If the names of the input fields has 57 characters **in total**, everything works 100%. If I add few characters and this number goes to 63, it becomes unstable and sometimes works - sometimes doesn't. If there's total of 70 or more characters, it never works.

So clearly something limits it, but what?

**Edit3**:

Huh, it's session size limit.. Damn it took long time to realize it.

I defined "file" as session driver, yet it doesn't generate any files in the location where it should, so it's still apparently using "cookie".
I gave Win10 users the rights to write files in the storage folder (and sub folders), but it still wont generate anything there.

Comment: Have you checked with `max_input_vars` in php.ini file?

Comment: @DilipHirapara It seems it was commented out, but now I set it to 1000, yet it didn't help. :/ Good catch though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end it happened becouse the session data didn't fit into a cookie. After long debugging (I was sure the issue was completely elsewhere) I changed my session driver to `file` inside `session.php`, but forgot to update `.env`..

So now everything works, by using `file` and/or `database` as session driver.

Comment: You saved my life ! I spent 2 days searching and yes it was because there was a change using `cookie` as default and then it came back to `file` but my version was the one with `cookie`.... now everything works !